# How can I change the visibility of a fusion table using the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-fusion-tables

I've read that I can change the visibility of a Google Fusion Table from private to unlisted or public using the Google Drive API v2.  I've tried setting the "shared" property to true to no avail (the result is a 200-OK but no change to "shared"), and the permissions look the same to me on a private and an unlisted table.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`drive.permissions.insert`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) method of the Drive API. You will add a permission to make the fusion table public. For more information, please read the [Drive SDK sharing guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing).

Comment: Thanks Ali.  That worked perfectly.  For others with this requirement, I made a REST POST call to permissions with four parameters in the body of the call:  "role": "reader", "type": "anyone", "value": "me", and "withLink": true.  This, interestingly, did not make a change to the file's (i.e. the Fusion Table's) userPermission, but did change the file's value of "shared" from false to true, changing the Fusion Table's visibility from Private to Unlisted.